Connection between Chern classes and Blow ups
I know that a very important topological invariant in Complex Geometry and Algebraic Geometry is the Chern class of a vector bundle. Recently, I came across a paper discussing a potential connection between Chern classes and the process of blowing up.
More precisely on CHERN CLASSES OF BLOW-UPS. But I can't fully understand the connection, lemma 1.1 hints at a method to compute the Chern classes on the normal bundle  by leveraging the blow up of $Y$ along $X$.
Could someone provide me with the underlying "recipe" or the skeleton of how the two are connected ?
Any beginners reference on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
You may assume that I know what Chern Classes are and how to blow up schemes along subschemes.

I'm not sure I understand your question. The paper finds an expression for the Chern classes of the tangent bundle of $\widetilde{Y}$, where $\widetilde{Y}$ is the blowup of a variety $Y$ along a regularly embedded subvariety $X$.

@MichaelAlbanese I thought the point was that the inverse image of $X$ was isomorphic to the normal bundle. If that's not the case, then my question doesn't make a lot of sense since we first consider the blow up and then look at Chern classes. I thought we could calculate the Chern classes of a variety by calculating the Chern clases of the blow up variety, which maybe easier.

I think it would be good to edit the question to make it self-contained, i.e., so pursuing and reading an external link isn't necessary. <> I haven't followed the link, but based on Michael's comment perhaps it's helpful to look into the Leray-Hirsch theorem as described in Kobayashi's Differential Geometry of Complex vector Bundles.

That is true, but in general, you would use the formula to calculate the Chern classes of $\widetilde{Y}$ from the Chern classes of $X$ and $Y$.

@MichaelAlbanese I see that's helpful, thank you. Is there any standard example I can work out, so I can get a better feeling of what we mean ?

I don't know of any, but you could take a look at section $15.4$ of Fulton's Intersection Theory.
